# How to add custom resualt to windows search everywhere

Tags: c#, search, windows-10, windows-rt

I trying to add custom result to windows search everywhere.
For example i typed 'MyApp settings' and navigate directly to settings inside my app.

I look at https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples but cannot find answerd.

I found many xml's like below, but cannot find any documentation about it.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PCSettings>
  <SearchableContent     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2013/SettingContent">
<ApplicationInformation>
  <AppID>windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel</AppID>
</ApplicationInformation>
<SettingIdentity>
  <PageID>SettingsPagePCSystemAutoPlay</PageID>
  <GroupID>SettingsGroupAutoplayDefaults</GroupID>
</SettingIdentity>
<SettingInformation>
  <Description>@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupAutoplayDefaults/Description}</Description>
  <HighKeywords>@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupAutoplayDefaults/HighKeywords}</HighKeywords>
  <Keywords>@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupAutoplayDefaults/Keywords}</Keywords>
  <LowKeywords>@{windows?ms-resource://Windows.UI.SettingsAppThreshold/SearchResources/SettingsGroupAutoplayDefaults/LowKeywords}</LowKeywords>
</SettingInformation>
```

Comment: You want to add [Cortana voice commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630430.aspx) for your app.

Comment: No. I seen cortana example, but i need text search result

Comment: Cortana voice commands can be invoked by text.